# Flower patch in Taverley?

Tags: runescape

I'm doing the new God Emissaries quest things, and on the third quest, I am asked to create a diversion near the flower patch in Taverley... Where is this flower patch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The flower patch is the same as the potato patch near the cows. The diversion varies with each player.